# from first file data match index of second file and get its before and after data in R

Tags: r, file-handling

I have two files
Details of first file is :

```
1 433
2 456
3 678
4 781
```

Like wise 10^3 rows
In second file

```
1 A
2 G
3 T
4 C
5 D
432 T
433 G
434 C
```

Likewise 10^7 rows 
I have to match the first file data with second file and then get the details of before and after rows.
for example 
from first file against 433 detailed result of

`432 T
 433 G
 434 C`

And later I want to fetch positions of only TGC and TGA with start and end position
I tried using for loop but on such a large loop won't work.

Comment: Where does `TGA` come from?

Comment: This pattern is in main file.

Comment: Using shift :-)

Comment: @Wen Can you please elaborate how using shift?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following function can solve all problems you might have, since the example dataset is so small.

```
fun <- function(i, x){
  res <- NULL
  x <- as.character(x)
  if(length(x) > 0) {
      if(i == 1)
        res <- x[seq_along(x)[1:2]]
      else
        if(i == length(x))
          res <- x[rev(seq_along(x))[2:1]]
        else
          res <- x[(i - 1):(i + 1)]
  }
  res
}

inx <- which(dat2[[1]] %in% dat1[[2]])
lapply(inx, fun, dat2[[2]])
#[[1]]
#[1] "T" "G" "C"
```

**Data.**

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "
1 433
2 456
3 678
4 781                   
")

dat2 <- read.table(text = "
1 A
2 G
3 T
4 C
5 D
432 T
433 G
434 C
")
```